# C: Are file scope variables available to all threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management

If I have a variable in a file outside a function declared and initialized as such:

```
static int i = 42;
```

Where is the variable `i` stored?   Is it the [Data section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data)?

If I have a variable in a file outside a function, declared but not initialized as such:

```
static int j;
```

Where is the variable `j` stored?   Is it the [BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#BSS)?

I presume that j will be initialized to zero by default, so what if I later do:

```
j = 1;
```

Where will `j` now be stored?

Now to the part I'm really interested in: are static file-scope variables available to all threads?

I'm asking because of course the heap is available to all threads, but each thread has its own stack and previously I had assumed that static file-scope variables are placed on the stack, just as variables declared inside a function.

Just out of curiosity - do the same storage rules for static file-scope variables also apply for global variables?

Comment: `static int i = 42;` goes into data section (even if declared inside a function); `static int j;` goes into bss section and stays there even after being written to (.bss is like .data, just not initialized, so it does not occupy space in executable image); `const static int x = 42;` goes into rdata section (.rdata is like .data, just not writeable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now to the part I'm really interested in: are static file-scope
>   variables available to all threads

Yes, all threads have access to the whole address space.

What is more interesting is that **the objects don't need to have static storage**, the way `i` and `j` do in your example. If you have an object on the stack of thread A and somehow manage to pass its address to thread B, B can access it without problems.

---

> do the same storage rules for static file-scope variables also aply
>   for global variables?

Both of these have what is called "static storage". In the context of a variable declared outside of any function `static` simply makes it invisible outside its translation unit.

Comment: In C11, it is implementation-defined what happens if a thread attempts to access another thread's variable with automatic or thread storage duration (via a pointer). In POSIX and most practical systems, it is allowed like you say.